# Cascaded sql delete

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to delete a table row in an Oracle database on which many other rows in other tables depend and on these rows other rows again and so on... 
The constraints have NO cascade set. 
Is there any tool or script which generates a delete script for this task?

Comment: It is called a trigger - please google it

Comment: Do you have primary/foreign key constraints between the tables, and if so [are they set to delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)?

Comment: The constraints have NO cascade set.

Comment: Query ALL_CONSTRAINTS to get the relationships, and then build a query to perform the delete from children first, working your way up to the parent.  There is always the urge to build this dynamically - that is generally a bad idea.  Some additional info https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=deleting-rows-from-parent-child-tables

Comment: I want to create the delete script only once with a single parameter which defines the root row.

Comment: I don't know whether you read contents written behind the link @Alex posted (probably not, it's a lot of text). So: if you re-create foreign key constraints and include the **ON DELETE CASCADE** option, you'd really delete only the master ("root", as you call it) row, and Oracle would delete all its children.

Comment: I cannot change the constraints and it would be a very dangerous option, imho :)